# In Oracle PL/SQL ,why I couldn't name the block using <<>>

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

In Oracle PL/SQL ,why I couldn't name the block using relevant sympols?
Am using PL/SQL Developer.Thanks in Advance.

**Whole Code :** I tried to type below code but after x number := 10 Exception comes.I couldn't type further.

```
<<outer_block>>
declare
x number := 10;
begin
 dbms_output.put_line('x is ' || x);
end;
```

**Code :**

```
SQL> <<block1>>
  2  declare
  3  x number := 10;
```

**Exception Trace :**

```
<<block1>>
declare
x number := 10

ORA-06550: line 5, column 0:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_
   LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || multiset member SUBMULTISET_
```

[image]

Comment: Error at line 5,so it should be something else. Can you share some more of the code snippet please?

Comment: you need to have a BEGIN and END as well.. like [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL#PL.2FSQL_Anonymous_Block)

Comment: named tags are really only useful inside of the begin/end section. And the anonymous block itself doesn't even start until you hit the declare line. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Thanks for all your replys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in PL/SQL Developer.  I'm a huge fan of PL/SQL Developer but the whole idea of the Command Window is wrong.  The entire feature is a bug.  Use the command line SQL*Plus instead.

Thousands of tools connect to Oracle.  They all work slightly differently and have different bugs.  For ad hoc development it doesn't matter very much, each developer can use the tool they are comfortable with.  SQL*Plus is pretty lousy for developing.

But when it comes to troubleshooting and deployments we need a tool that will always work the same way, on all platforms.  That tool is SQL*Plus.

Simulating SQL*Plus is a horrible idea.  Unless it can be done 100% accurately it ruins the main benefit of using SQL*Plus - consistency.  Always use the real SQL*Plus, not an imitation.

---

**Update**

As others have pointed out, this is not the correct way to use labels.  However, the syntax is still technically valid and will run in SQL*Plus and some other environments without error.

Comment: Thanks for all your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `<<Name>>` syntax is for naming loops. Useful when you have nested loops and need to use the EXIT loop_name WHEN ... syntax to control which loop to exit.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/controlstructures.htm#BABJCCFJ
for an example